# Регулярные выражения в С++: отличия POSIX от PCRE

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt

В чем отличие синтаксиса POSIX- и PCRE- регулярных выражений? 
Если у меня есть POSIX-выражение в `std::regex`, и мне его надо написать с помощью `QRegularExpression`, где поддерживается только PCRE, могу ли я просто подставить то же выражение и ожидать корректного результата?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это зависит от выражения. По каждой части выражения можно проконсультироваться на [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) — там Вы можете посмотреть как та или иная часть выражения записывается в том или ином формате.

А вообще, проще всего записать в PCRE и исползовать его и в `std::regex` и в `QRegularExpression`